# How to prove the given property of spherical harmonics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spherical-harmonics

How to prove:

$$
\int^\pi_0\int^{2\pi}_0 Y_{l'',m''_l}(\theta,\phi) Y_{l',m'_l}(\theta,\phi) Y_{l,m_l}(\theta,\phi) \sin\theta \,d\theta \,d\phi = 0
$$
unless $l, l',$ and $l''$ are integers that can form the sides of a trangle and $m_l+m_l'+m_l''=0$

$Y_{l,m_l}(\theta,\phi)$ are spherical harmonics

Can I somehow make use of the orthogonality of the spherical harmonics ?
i.e,
$$
\int^\pi_0\int^{2\pi}_0 Y_{l,m_l}(\theta,\phi) Y_{l',m_l'}(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta \, d\theta \, d\phi=\delta_{l,l'}\delta_{m_l,m_l'}
$$

**Note:** To understand the context, please check [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=QbQJAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA780&ots=_IjQdogdOY&dq=Physical%20Chemistry%3A%20Quanta%2C%20Matter%2C%20and%20Change%20By%20Peter%20Atkins%20page%20Spectral%20linewidths&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Note the proper way to set $\sin\theta$ in MathJax, as seen in my edit to this question. $\qquad$